# Testing existing Evernote client code with Evernote China (Yinxiang Biji) service

Tags: macos, evernote

I have an OS X application that has been integrated with Evernote's API since 2009. I have been getting more frequent requests to support Evernote's Chinese service, Yinxiang Biji. This is a separate service that uses the same API but a different login point.

Evernote's API includes a bootstrap system which should auto-determine whether to connect to www.evernote.com or app.yinxiang.com, based on IP address and locale. However, the bootstrap code does not seem to be working with my Chinese customers, at least in my application.

Is there any way I can test this in the US with an English locale? I've taken the latest Evernote SDK Mac and sample client (https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-mac) and made the minor changes to that code to use my company's consumerKey and consumerSecret. The code will connect to the US service but even if I force the session to use Yinxiang via:

```
session.host = BootstrapServerBaseURLStringCN;
```

in EvernoteSession.m's +setSharedSessionHost code, I cannot get it to even attempt a login to yinxiang, as it immediately switches back to Evernote International. At this point I'm just looking for an yinxiang login screen.

Am I missing some type of authorization to attempt US-based connections?

Comment: Did you work out how to test a Yinxiang Biji connection?

Comment: Fortunately I had some customers in China that assisted.

Comment: I also have the same issue on iOS SDK, is there anything new for this?

Comment: Nothing new AFAIK.

Comment: That is unfortunate, I have a user who asked for Evernote support in China, but I cannot do anything for him yet..